# How to search for specific structure from Structures of data array and read using fread?

Tags: c, struct, fread, fseek, strstr

My text file looks like this,

**Person.txt**

```
John 
{
   sex = "Male";
   age = 23;
};

Sara 
{
   sex = "Female";
   age = 23;
};

stephan 
{
   sex = "Male";
   age = 25;
};
```

I want to fetch the specific person's data based on the request. For Instance, I got a request to fetch Stephan's data. I guess, first I need to read the person.txt to search for Stephan and then fetch his information. I am bit confused to do this in a right way using fread. Here is my code,

```
struct personS
{
  int age;
  char sex[7];
} personS;

FILE *fp;
void check_person_data(const char *name, int *age, const char *sex)               
{
  PersonS *person;

  if((fp=fopen("Person.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    printf("File reading error\n");

  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  size = ftell(fp);
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
  char buffer[size];

  while(fread(buffer, size, 1, fp) != NULL)
  {
   if((strstr(buffer, name)) != NULL)
   { 
     printf("Match found \n");
     fread(&person, sizeof(struct personS), 1, fp);    
     *age = person->age;
     *sex = person->sex;       
   }
   else
    printf("Match not found \n");        
  }   
 fclose(fp);
}
```

I did fread 2 times, one to search for string and other to fetch the structure. Is it correct way of doing it or any other better way?

Comment: I suggest you use `fgets` to read a text file with lines of unknown length. It reads data to (and including) the next line break, so although you need enough space to read the line into, you don't need to know how long it is *before* you read it. On the other hand `fread` is generally used for binary information of known size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example seems to be a text file that could be read with `fgets()` and `sscanf()`. The reading of the file to find a matching name does not require the structure so it is omitted. Once the values have been read, the calling function could put them into the structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int check_person_data(char *name, int *age, char *sex)
{
    char buffer[50] = {0};
    FILE *fp;

    if ( ( fp = fopen ( "person.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf ( "file reading error\n");
        return 2;
    }

    while ( fgets ( buffer, sizeof ( buffer), fp)) {
        if ( buffer[0] == '\n') {
            continue;//blank line
        }
        if ( buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] == '\n') {
            buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';//remove trailing newline
        }
        if ( strcmp ( buffer, name) == 0) {//found match
            while ( fgets ( buffer, sizeof ( buffer), fp)) {
                if ( strstr ( buffer, "sex")) {//does the line contain sex
                    if ( ( sscanf ( buffer, " %*[^\"\n]\"%6[^;\"\n]", sex)) != 1) {//scan and discard up to a ", scan " and scan up to six characters to next "
                        return 1;//bad record
                    }
                }
                if ( strstr ( buffer, "age")) {//does the line contain age
                    if ( ( sscanf ( buffer, " %*[^=\n]=%d", age)) != 1) {// scan and discard up to an =, scan = and scan an integer
                        return 1;//bad record
                    }
                }
                if ( strstr ( buffer, "};")) {//does the line contain };
                    break;//found end of record
                }
            }
            return 0;//found the matching name
        }
        else {//did not match. read the remaining lines of record
            while ( fgets ( buffer, sizeof ( buffer), fp)) {
                if ( strstr ( buffer, "};")) {//does the line contain };
                    break;//found end of record
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose ( fp);
    return 1;//match not found
}

int main()
{
    char name[30] = {0};
    char sex[7] = {0};
    int age = 0;

    strcpy ( name, "stephan");
    if ( ( check_person_data ( name, &age, sex)) == 0) {
        printf ( "name %s age %d sex %s\n", name, age, sex);
    }
    else {
        printf ( "%s not found\n", name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm always pleased to see sscanf of an intermediate buffer used to parse stuff.

Comment: Your solution has helped me, thanks. Now I have another question with the format string. For example, value = "0x1000"; I read this line with fgets and got stuck while processing the format. I tried with  sscanf(buffer, " %*[^\"\n]\"%D[^;\"\n]", keyIntValue); and also with %x but doesn't work. Help please?

Answer (score 0):

```
fread(&person, sizeof(struct personS), 1, fp);
```

person now its a copy of data in your file , when you need to change the data of file you cant just change the copy , you need to `fwrite(..)` the new data that you have change